# Log a message to text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that reads the last mesage and if it contains `custom fields:` then respond with a message. I want to log that entire message into a txt file. How can I do it?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'mytoken'; // Token goes here.

client.login(token); // login the bot with your token.

client.on('message', message => {


    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('custom field:'))
        message.channel.send("Custom field detected");


});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.appendFile('log.txt', message.content, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Using append is needed unless you want multiple logfiles.
You'll also need to include fs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But isn't reading the contents of a bot, it logs the messages i receive, but not from a bot

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, sorry

Answer (score 0):

**You will need FS (File-System):**

```
npm install fs
```

After you have installed it, make sure you can you use it in your code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

And then when you're using it (I recommend you do not put it in the same place as when you have the commands, meaning you make another `client.on('message', message)` thing):

```
var readmessagefile = fs.readFileSync('{File Name}', 'utf-8'));
var writemessagefile = fs.writeFileSync('{File Name}', 'Time - ' + message.createdAt + ' User - ' + message.member.user.username + ': ' message.content + readmessagefile)
```

All of this, and your code together looks like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'mytoken'; // Token goes here.
const fs = require('fs');

client.login(token); // login the bot with your token.

client.on('message', message => {
     var readmessagefile = fs.readFileSync('{File Name}', 'utf-8'));
     var writemessagefile = fs.writeFileSync('{File Name}', 'Time - ' + 
     message.createdAt + ' User - ' + message.member.user.username + ': ' 
     message.content + readmessagefile)
});
client.on('message', message => {
     //Commands here
});
```

Make sure you create a .txt file, and then change "{File Name}"s to your file name plus ".txt".

I hope this help with your bot.